# Functions of several variables

Tags: multivariable-calculus

If $f(x,y) = x^2 + xy + y^2 - 3x + 4y - 5$. I know the domain is $\mathbb R^2$. How to determine the image of f is my issue.

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem? What have you tried? Where are you running into trouble?

Comment: Also, why have you chosen the tag "complex analysis"? Your question doesn't seem to have anything to do with complex analysis.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Thanks. I will do that after you.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at my answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3619647/399263

You can always translate conics to cancel terms in $x,y$.

$f(x+a,y+b)=x^2+(-3+b+2a)x+xy+y^2+(2b+4+a)y+[\cdots]$

Solve $\begin{cases}2a+b-3=0\\2b+4+a=0\end{cases}\iff \begin{cases}a=\frac{10}3\\b=-\frac {11}3\end{cases}$

$$f(x+a,y+b)=\overbrace{(x^2+xy+y^2)}^{\ge 0}-\dfrac{52}3$$

In this case $x^2+xy+y^2\ge 0$ is always positive (discriminant $-3y^2<0$) with equality for $x=y=0$.

Thus $f$ has a minimum for $(x+a,y+b)=(0,0)\iff (x=-a,y=-b)$ of value $-\dfrac{52}3$.

Also $f$ is unbounded above since for instance $f(x,0)=x^2-3x-5$ is unbounded above.

Comment: This is great! Now I see where to continue with the problem.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** This function is differentiable and has a unique critical point. It is helpful to determine whether this critical point is a saddle point, a maximum, or a minimum.

For instance, if the critical point is a local maximum and if that local maximum is also a global maximum, then the function attains a unique maximum but it unbounded below, which means that the range is of the form $(-\infty,c]$ for some $c \in \Bbb R$.

---

Alternatively, it would suffice to show that this function is convex.

Comment: As this is true in dimension $1$ it's wrong in dimension $2$.  Take $x^3+y^3-xy$.  It has only one minimum in $(1/6,1/12)$, but $\lim_{x\to-\infty}x^3+y^3-xy=-\infty$ for any fixed $y$.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe one minimum, but two critical points

Comment: @MichaelHoppe Also I believe the (local) minimum is at $(1/3,1/3)$. However, I realize now that I'm not sure about my statement, even if we assume that the critical point is unique.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe In fact, my suspicion was [incorrect after all](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/121326/81360).

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** Consider the qadratic form
$$Q(x,y,z)= x^2 + xy + y^2 - 3xz + 4yz - 5z^2$$

Note that
$$f(x,y)=Q(x,y,1)$$

$Q$ corresponds to the symmetric matrix
$$A= \begin{bmatrix}
1 & \frac{1}{2} &\frac{-3}{2} \\
\frac{1}{2} & 1 & 2\\
\frac{-3}{2}&2 & -5 
\end{bmatrix}$$

Now, orthogonally diagonalize $A$, and do the corresponding change of variable $\begin{bmatrix} a \\ b \\ c \end{bmatrix} = P\begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \\ z\end{bmatrix} $ to transform $Q$ to the form
$$Q(a,b,c)=\alpha a^2 + \beta b^2+ \gamma c^2$$

Swicth $a,b,c$ back to $x,y,z$ and set $z=1$.